# JAVA_HOME variable ERROR: /usr/bin/java/jdk1.6.0_20 does not exist. JAVA_HOME is not set correctly

Tags: java

I'm trying to run

```
./runcat.sh
```

it gives me an error saying

> ERROR: /usr/bin/java/jdk1.6.0_20 does not exist. JAVA_HOME is not set
>   correctly.

I did this

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java/jdk1.6.0_20 export JAVA_HOME
```

In the official document it says `export JAVA_HOME=Java_home_directory`
some one please help...

Comment: Does the directory /usr/bin/java/jdk1.6.0_20 exist and does it have Java installed into it?

Comment: YES IT EXISTS java is installed henry

Comment: According to your comment on the answer it should be /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20 and not /usr/bin/java/jdk1.6.0_20

Comment: Yes its working your right thank you so much henry and Oscar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, the directory `/usr/bin/java/jdk1.6.0_20`does not exist.

Your JAVA home dir must be somewhereelse. You should search for it and change `JAVA_HOME` environment variable accordingly.

You could search the `JAVA_HOME` with something like:

```
 find / -name java
```

**EDIT**
If, for example, this command returns `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0.20/jre/bin/java` then your `JAVA_HOME` is:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0.20/jre/
```

Comment: This is what i got so what will be my JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin/java
/usr/java
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0.20/jre/bin/java
Thank you very much

Comment: [DM_HJ]]$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/bin/java export JAVA_HOME
[DM_HJ]$ ./runclient.sh                                            ERROR: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/bin/java does not exist. JAVA_HOME is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can set JAVA_HOME=JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java/jdk1.6.0_20 in .bashrc 
and then execute the command "source .bashrc"